# How to define a table in QxORM with multiple primary keys, one of them is a "many to one" relation to an other table

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qxorm

What is the right way to define a table (“secondtable”) with multiple primary key, one of them (“|first_table_key”)  is a “many to one” relation to another table (“firsttable”)?

This doesen't work because of multiple definitions of “first_table_key”!

```
namespace qx 
{
template <> void register_class(QxClass<secondtable> & t)
{
   t.id(&secondtable::m_id, “second_table _key|first_table_key”);
   t.data(&secondtable::m_text, "second_table_text");
   t.relationManyToOne(&secondtable::m_firsttable, “first_table_key”);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
namespace qx 
{
template <> void register_class(QxClass<secondtable> & t)
{
   t.id(&secondtable::m_id, “second_table _key|first_table_key”);
   t.data(&secondtable::m_text, "second_table_text");
   qx::IxSqlRelation * pRelation = t.relationManyToOne(&secondtable::m_firsttable, “first_table”);
   pRelation->getDataMember()->setName("first_table_key");
}
}
```

As you can see, you can define your relation with another key (*first_table*), which is not the same key as your primary key (*first_table_key*). And then, just put the correct name of your relation using *pRelation->getDataMember()->setName()* method.